# Jesus and Mohammed (SAW) in the Quran

Tags: quran, prophet-muhammad, prophet-isa

Why does the Qur’an talk about Jesus more often than Muhammad?

Comment: It does not. Rather Jesus  عليه السلام  is 'named' more often than Muhammad ﷺ, while Muhammad ﷺ is usually referred to implicitly or by a pronoun or title.

Answer (score 1):

The whole qur'an is addressing Muhammad () and through him his ummah.
If the qur'an speaks about 'Isa () it is rather in a historical context or for the purpose of teaching Muhammad () and his ummah and reminding them.